# Problem with in-text citations

Tags: biblatex

I am writing a lengthy document, having many citations and following the APA citations style. I would like the in-text citations of multiple authors to have this character "&" instead of the word "and".

For example, this is how currently one of my in-text citations looks like: (Johnsson **and** Ammari, 2016).

While this is how I would like it to be:

> (Johnsson **&** Ammari, 2016).

I also have the following in my main file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,  citestyle=apa, firstinits=true , language=ngerman ]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
```

Comment: Can you please add a full example document that shows what you are doing at the moment (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). I just ran a short test and both `\autocite` and `\parencite` gave me "(Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)". Are you using `(\cite{sigfridsson})`? If so, please use `\autocite{sigfridsson}` or `\parencite{sigfridsson}` instead.

Comment: @moewe, I used `\cite`. But now, as I have just found out, `\autocite` solves this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The APA style guide wants an ampersand in citations only when the names are set in parentheses. Naturally `biblatex-apa` follows these rules as closely as possible.

With

```
\autocite{sigfridsson}
```

you get

> (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)

as desired. It should never be necessary to add parentheses around a `biblatex` cite command manually, there is almost always a command that does that for you automatically. And if you write the parentheses yourself, `biblatex` does not know about them and can't switch to the ampersand.

`\cite` and `\textcite` will both give "und"/"and".  `\nptextcite` will give the same output as `\parencite`/`\autocite` but without the parentheses. `\nptextcite` can be used if you want to cite when you are already in parentheses.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\parencite{sigfridsson}

\cite{sigfridsson}

\textcite{sigfridsson}

\nptextcite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//(Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//Sigfridsson und Ryde, 1998//Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998)//Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998//Literatur//Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. (1998). Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 19(4), 377–395. doi:10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P]